# Better way to copy same data in several lines matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to add the same data in different lines using Matlab. In my first version, I copied the data as shown in the code below.
Is there a better way to do that?

```
data=[-5:1:14;-5:1:14;-5:1:14;-5:1:14;]
```

answer:

```
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `repmat`

```
repmat(-5:14,4)
```

or `kron`

```
kron(-5:14,ones(4,1))
```

Comment: kron is what i want